# Where can I find some forgotten inventions of our Vedic Era?

Tags: history, manuscripts

I recently watched Sadhguru's video on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxPlm44PCK0) where he said that Pushpak Viman(aeroplanes) was already built by us in Vedic Era.

I am aware that our great history has done many developments in various fields for example,in medicine(ayurveda),mathematics,space exploration,etc..which is in use even till this date,but it is present today, because the knowledge was taught and passed on to future generations.

My question: Is it possible that many of our great ancestors had already invented things that the world is yet to see and written about the inventions in some books or manuscripts and was forgotten?

If yes,is it possible for me to find such manuscripts and try to revive them?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Feel free to take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted.  :)

Comment: @Vivikta Thanks,I have taken the tour.

Answer (score 0):

Ancient India was no doubt a pioneer in the exploration of knowledge. There is no proof to suggest they had planes, iPhones, or other devices we have now. They likely never will be either, because most of what is claimed to be found is made up by "Hindus" who don't even bother reading scripture. That being said mathematics, astronomy, metallurgy, and medicine were indeed studied and expanded upon. Even if some of the specific practices are no longer up to date. Most Vedic texts discuss maths in terms of geometry and for practical use in rituals. Other treatises on math are made by Brahmagupta, Aryabhatta, etc. and you can find their works in the archive online. For Astronomy look no further than Jyotish Shastras and Brihat Samhita. Medicine is discussed in Atharvaveda and Sushruta Samhita. If however, you want to find other possible discoveries made by ancient Indians. Many old temples may have libraries although usually only accessible to priests. You may also, but I warn you check Padmanabhaswamy temple's secret gates which could contain sacred knowledge. However, accessing all these is nearly impossible, and doing so would likely disrupt the deity and could lead to curses if you believe in such (which I do). If your intentions are pure to gather sacred knowledge and you take the steps of devotion and study what is known, then discovery and illumination will surely come. However, what use is all this material knowledge friend science already gave us a lot of stuff and the intellect of the world together has helped us, focus on the philosophy that is where true knowledge is grounded.