# Relation between Modern Physics and Hinduism

Tags: bhagavad-gita, philosophy, sankhya

I have been reading Parahamansa Yogananda's book for some time and I have noticed some relation between String theory, modern physics and Spirituality (sankhya yoga).

1. We say in Sankhya yoga that we are like waves on the ocean of the One Spirit-giving a sense of materialization of the body when the string of our life (the soul) is surrounded by moha and maya and karmic tendencies, it manifests itself, but again we should remember that we fundamentally are just souls. It also promotes quantization of the Spirit in space and it's omnipresent nature, which seem to coincide with the view of strings being fundamental or of the fundamental particles-and the idea that certain Quantum Fields dominate space. Similarly, I also just seem to have this thought of String Theory being intricately connected to here. Can anyone explain how could that relation be? like dimension wise, energy wise, manifestation wise, the notion that certain types of frequencies of vibration give rise to a particular type of string (or in this case manifestations of the spirit?)
2. Also, I have *found (if not earlier already)* method of how taking on new bodies could be done or how communication with the higher world is prohibited to our will- imagine that we are in flatland (I hope everyone is familiar with the concept, else please check  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnURElCzGc0 ), and the ghosts/devas/any other higher beings are there, but we being trapped (or rather not even knowing we are trapped for the lack of knowledge of other dimensions or their nature-as the situation with the 10 dimensions is today), cannot possibly contact them or sense them. Only we can see or sense a fragment of them like only a slice of a 3D being can be seen in flatland if the residents of flatland are not taken to the unknown dimensions to them (up and down). We, as much as our bodies, living in flatland are 2D. So the ghost doesn't need to take on a new body or change dimensions, but can just come into our flatland (here the ghost being a 3D object), and while only his slice is visible- which would very much look to us as a body, the ghost can do whatever he wants, and in a sense take possession over someone. So, the ghost encounters might just be real and not fictitious.
3. Does this shloka

*yadā te moha-kalilaṁ buddhir vyatitariṣhyati
tadā gantāsi nirvedaṁ śhrotavyasya śhrutasya cha*

in any sense promote Eternalism-because it says you can basically escape time (does it suggest there is a block universe of which we are a part as humans thus we experience the myth of time)?

Comment: Since you are new to the site you may not know that here we are not allowed to co relate concepts of Science and those of religion. It might be an interesting topic but not allowed on this site.

Comment: Sir then can you please tell me where to post these questions? Philosophy stack exchange wont accept them and tag them being promoting religion

Comment: I don't think there is any SE site where you can ask this. So you have to try other sites or forums.

Comment: @Rickross Can it be a reason for my question (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/50955/27332) being unanswered..Is my question answerable?Should I raise bounty for my question?

Comment: I think it is answerable and someone might do it. Regarding bounty, you can wait for a few more days and then offer a bounty if it's its still unanswered even then. @RamanujanXXV

Comment: I haven't found such site where such thing are discussed nor am I personally a subscriber to Hinduism as a relegion, but I can recommend you a book named "Shadows of the mind" by roger penrose. It tries to describe what conciousness is mathematiaclly.